# How to provide consistency of tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table `Orders`. Also there are three tables `AcceptedOrders, CanceledOrders, CompletedOrders` indicate states of order with the following fields structure each one:

```
order_id | executor_id | created_at
```

Also table `OrderApplicants` contains who was assigned to the order.

So, executor can accept, cancel or complete the order. How to avoid to add a status of order into `AcceptedOrders, CanceledOrders, CompletedOrders` if executor is absent in `OrderApplicants` table?

Another issue user can not set `CompletedOrders` if there was not setted status inside `AcceptedOrders`. The same thing can not can set status cancel into `CanceledOrders` if there is not status in `AcceptedOrders`.

So, how to provide consistency among tables?

Structure od tables:

```
Table Order
  order_id | create_at | status | executor_id

Table OrderApplicants
  order_id | executor_id | created_at

Table AcceptedOrders
  order_id | executor_id | created_at

Table CanceledOrders
  order_id | executor_id | created_at

Table CompletedOrders
  order_id | executor_id | created_at
```

I decied to review my structure and made this:

```
Orders
----------
order_id (pk)
user_id (fk)
appliciant_id (fk)

OrderAppliciants
-----------------
user_id (fk)
order_id (fk)

OrderStatusHistory
-----------------
order_id (fk)
status (0, 1, 2)
created_at

Users
--------------
user_id (pk)
type (0, 1, 2)
name
```

So, I wonder should I add `appliciant_id` into `OrderAppliciants`? I doubt because user_id is foreign key already.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the table structures you have, including the foreign key constraints you have.

Comment: *Also there are three tables AcceptedOrders, CanceledOrders, CompletedOrders indicate states of order* Denormalization. Why?

Comment: Why do you have additional tables `AcceptedOrders`, `CanceledOrders` and `CompletedOrders` and not something like `Status` in the `Orders` table, which can be "Accepted", "Canceled" or "Completed"?

Comment: Why do you need 3 separate tables for the order status? Why wouldn’t just status column in orders table do?

Comment: Why do you have additional tables - becasue I need to store history of status changes by appliciants. So I also have status on `Order` that is setted by trigger

Comment: As the other commenters already wrote use **one** table for all the orders. Add a status column to it. You can use a trigger to control the changes of status. If the old status doesn't allow to change to the new status, throw an error.

Comment: You should create table status_change, where you would have id, id_of_order, changed_to and datetime. This would solve your problem

Comment: So, do you mean replace three table on the one and add status field with thee different values indicate status?

Comment: Maybe one table is enough. Maybe you need in two tables - Orders and Actions. We don't know...

Comment: I completely agree with Krystof18 here. if the objective is to keep track of the history you don't need three tables at all. Add the status in the Order table and create another one to keep just the changes: `orderId, dateOfChange, user, previous_status, new_status`
This will make your validation easier because you can just make the `executor_id` not null and it would prevent that record from being added without it.

Comment: If you got the orders in three tables, one for each status, you can end up with one order being stored in each of the tables (or two of them). What is its status then, you got three (two) different ones? The `executor_id`s might also contradict each other. To avoid that inconsistency, you should really keep the order in *one* table. Status is an attribute of an order and doesn't spawn a whole new entity. It should be a simple (enum) column.

Comment: You also don't need OrderApplicants, just get rid of it as you already have executor_id in Order. Now if you need to keep every single change in an order tracked then I would recommend an auditing system instead.

Comment: No, I need table OrderAppliciants, because among them algorithm will select best offer

Comment: Based on the fields you shared how will the algorithm know who did the best offer as there is nothing on those tables to identify it? If that is the case you would need a OrderOffer table (the naming would improve a lot the objective of it) and the fields would be something like: orderId, executor_id, date, offer

Comment: I updated the question with more strict tables, check out this

Comment: All in all, the extended discussion shows this gets out of hand. That's the problem with such "Help me make my data model" questions. They're typically too broad for SO, unless it is a specific question about a specific design decision. They would require detailed knowledge about what should be modeled in the real world where even a small scope typically raises a lot of questions during the design process. And SO is designed as a Q & A platform and not for such interactive processes. Voting to close because it needs more focus.

Comment: Okay I agree with you, you can close it

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to get rid of all tables except `orders` and `order_aplicants`

I would leave `orders` as it is. - `status` in `orders` could be `fk` to `status_history.id`

Then for storing the history of order status I’d make `status_history` table with structure like this:

`id | order_id | changed_to | datetime`

and maybe `executor_id` for keeping log of who did what

Comment: Where to store status? Also in status_history?

Comment: Either you can store it in orders as column status, or you can query last status_history record for given order id to get it